# pandas dataframe search with contains and get the row number

Tags: python, pandas

In a dataframe , I want to search for a string in on the first column and on finding that string , I would like to get the row number and assign it as a variable,

my dataframe looks something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['xx', '--- bios ---', 'yy', 'zz', '--- os ---'],'B': ['rat', '', 'winter', 'host','']})
```

I am trying to get row number of the string and assign it to a variable ,as below

```
var = df.iloc[:,0].str.contains('--- bios ---').index
```

where --- bios --- is the search word and I am trying to get the index

but I am not getting the desired output, output i am expecting is 4 which is the row number

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  You've received several bits of advice and it doesn't appear to have met your needs.  Given the caliber of that help, it is likely that you need to show us an example to demonstrate what you are looking for without ambiguity.

Comment: Here is how my date frame looks like , hope this more specific , df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['xx', '--- bios ---', 'yy', 'zz', '--- os ---'],'B': ['', 'rat', 'winter', 'host','']})

Comment: [edit] your question and include that information.  Also include what you expect to get back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`df.iloc[:,0].str.contains('--- bios ---')` still has the same (full) index as `df`. You may want:

```
df.index[df.iloc[:,0].str.contains('--- bios ---')]
```

or:

```
df[df.iloc[:,0].str.contains('--- bios ---')].index
```

Comment: I want the row number of this string

Comment: Yes, try those lines, either should give you the rows where that happens.

Comment: I guess it worked, however in the dataframe I am working with , the column contains empty value and so this returns this error "Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values"... i tried passing na = True , it then reset the row index to 0 ... which is not what I am looking for

Comment: Use `df.iloc[:,0].str.contains('--- bios ---')==True`?

Comment: `df.iloc[:, 0].str.contains('--- bios ---').argmax()` returns the position.  `df.iloc[:, 0].str.contains('--- bios ---').idxmax()` returns the associated index value.

Comment: @ Quang Hoang, I went with your approach, with a small modification as below var = ((df[df.iloc[:,0].str.contains('--- bios ---',na=False)].index).values)[0]

Answer (score 3):

#### `query`

```
q = "--- bios ---"
c = df.columns[0]

df.query(f'"{q}" in {c}').index
```